# Unable to observe changes in Mutable Live data List

Tags: kotlin

In my Data class I am having

```
var education: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<DocRegEducation>> =  
MutableLiveData(ArrayList<DocRegEducation>()),
```

in fragment i am adding value

```
 docViewModel.doctorRegisterModel.value?.education?.value?.add(doc_reg_edu)
```

and observing

```
 docViewModel.doctorRegisterModel.value?.education?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it?.let {
                logd("reached education changes observed")
                educationAdapter.setData(it) }
        })
```

but the changes are not observed

Comment: Observer will work when you set the value (we can also call it change the reference) of the mutable live data which is your list not elements in list, you are adding elements in the list not changing the whole list.

Comment: adding the elements to arraylist is also modifying the arraylist right

Comment: ya, modifying the array list, not reference of array list, but observer will work if we modify the arraylist reference.

Comment: so how to modify the arraylist instead of reference which is in a dataclass

Comment: Just use a state variable, which helps you to notify the list or set new data, for example use mutable live data with long, and when you add element in list, then update the time on long mutable live data and on that observer you can use set data for list

Comment: Hi any reference please

Comment: I am answering you question, pls. try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ViewModel:

```
val educationList = ArrayList<DocRegEducation>()
val educationListState = MutableLiveData<Long>(0L)


fun setNewData(data:DogRegEducation){
// adding data for list here
educationList.add(data);
// changing state with respect to time value to observe on view side
educationListState.value = System.currentTimeMillis()

}
```

On View Side:

```
docViewModel.educationListState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
               
   // update the adapter on state change when item is added
   educationAdapter.setData(docViewModel.educationList) 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a very common problem for all new Kotlin developers (including me). Here,  the array reference is still the same. So, you have to create a new array for each element change and post it again.

Here is the example.

```
private val _lstAvailability: MutableLiveData<List<AppointmentsItem>> =
        MutableLiveData(emptyList()) 

// Create new mutable list reference
val duplicateList: MutableList<AppointmentsItem> = mutableListOf()

// add all possible AppointmentsItem info here like
duplicate.add(AppointmentsItem("item1"))
duplicate.add(AppointmentsItem("item2"))
duplicate.add(AppointmentsItem("item3"))

// Copy the old items into duplicate list, if needed
_lstAvailability.value.forEach {duplicateList.add(it.copy())}


//Finally update your livedata with new reference
_lstAvailability.value = duplicateList
```